# Install UnitySocketIO in Unity3d Indie

Tags: dll, socket.io, installation, unity-game-engine

The documentation for UnitySocketIO says "Copy all the DLLS locating in the file of /bin/Debug/ to your project." However, after I do this I can't instantiate a Client. How do you properly install UnitySocketIO in Unity3d Indie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that they are (.NET) DLLs, you will have to put them in a folder named "Plugins" within your "Assets" folder.

[image]

This "Plugins" folder can be in any sub-folder, if you have a different organisation.

From then on it's a simple

```c#
using SocketIOClient;
```

in your code, and you should be good to go.

Comment: i know this is an old question but im trying to do this myself and am just wondering do you put the soketio folder into the plugins folder or jus the dll's in the debug folder???

Comment: Just the DLLs should suffice I think. Do you encounter a specific issue?